# sweetalert2 - How to show loading animation icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I am using sweetalert2 for the alert message. Here is my code:

```
this.$swal({                        
    icon: 'warning',
    html: 'Please be patient, it can take up to several minutes to generate a test.',
    showCloseButton: false,
    showCancelButton: true,
    showConfirmButton: false,
    allowOutsideClick : false, 
    focusConfirm: false,                        
    cancelButtonText : 'Cancel Test',
    customClass: {
        confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
        cancelButton: 'btn btn-outline-danger ml-1',
    },
    buttonsStyling: false,
}).then(( result ) => {
    if( result.isDismissed ) {
        this.isTestStop = true;
    }                        
});
```

The output is:

[image]

**As you see the icon is alert icon but how can I show the loading icon here?**

Answer (score 1):

Remove the icon property, and add your image into the html.

```
this.$swal({                        

    html: '<div><img src="my-loading-icon.gif" /></div><div>Please be patient, it can take up to several minutes to generate a test.</div>',
    showCloseButton: false,
    showCancelButton: true,
    showConfirmButton: false,
    allowOutsideClick : false, 
    focusConfirm: false,                        
    cancelButtonText : 'Cancel Test',
    customClass: {
        confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
        cancelButton: 'btn btn-outline-danger ml-1',
    },
    buttonsStyling: false,
}).then(( result ) => {
    if( result.isDismissed ) {
        this.isTestStop = true;
    }                        
})
```

;

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I use vue-bootstrap class for the loading?